# DAL mapping efficiency

Tags: c#, performance, sql, sql-server, asynchronous

I am wondering if I can make these classes a bit more efficient.

**Test Results**

*Single Run*

- Method 1: 5 Columns - Text Query - 81178 Records = 00:00:00.6390366
  secs
- Method 2: 5 Columns - Text Query - 81178 Records = 00:00:00.5360307
  secs

*10 Run Loop*

- Method 1: 5 Columns - Text Query - 81178 Records = 00:00:05.3253045
  secs
- Method 2: 5 Columns - Text Query - 81178 Records = 00:00:05.0912912
  secs

*100 Run Loop*

- Method 1: 5 Columns - Text Query - 81178 Records = 00:00:54.1270959
  secs
- Method 2: 5 Columns - Text Query - 81178 Records = 00:00:53.8710813
  secs

All 3 attempts for both methods never peak over 25% CPU usage.

As you can see there really is no significant improvement over either method, and method 2 (judging by CPU usage) does not seem to multi-thread.

I am thinking that if I can get rid of my usage of reflection to map the columns to strongly-typed classes that it would make a significant boost to both methods performance, and I am sure that I can make improvements to the asyncronicity of method 2 as well... I just don't know how.

**WrapperTest.cs**

```
    private static IList<T> Map<T>(DbDataReader dr) where T : new()
    {
        try
        {
            // initialize our returnable list
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            // fire up the lamda mapping
            var converter = new Converter<T>();
            // read in each row, and properly map it to our T object
            var obj = converter.CreateItemFromRow(dr);

            // reutrn it
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Catch an exception if any, an write it out to our logging mechanism, in addition to adding it our returnable message property
            _Msg += "Wrapper.Map Exception: " + ex.Message;
            ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(ex, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.Wrapper.Map", _Msg);
            // make sure this method returns a default List
            return default(List<T>);
        }
    }
```

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459583/asyncronous-while-loop).

The code above definitely runs more efficiently now.  Is there any way to make it better?

Comment: you should try to break this up into several questions.

Comment: you can also link to the other questions that you have posted since it is the same application.  I think that is reasonable.

Comment: Private fields naming convention is `_field`, not `_Field`... I guess VB is rubbing off on your C#, don't worry,  soon your C# will rub off on your VB ;)

Comment: Any reasons you are not using existing ORM like LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: I don't think EF is C#-specific (although I never tried with VB), @tia is right, an ORM would make your like much easier. Besides L2S isn't rwally an ORM so you can start with that :) ....as for the naming, no, it doesn't really matter. Just as long as you're consistent through.

Comment: There's also lightweight project like FastMember - https://code.google.com/p/fast-member/, which does exactly what you are doing. For the sake of Code Review, I'll come back to your code on my weekend. I think the performance could be improved by skip using reflection for setting value.

Comment: In every iteration, you use CreateItemFromRow(). Why dont you call that once, and then store the indexes, so you can simply refer the rest of the table by index? That would speed things up significantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ expression compilation to generate mapping code at runtime. The concept is to generate a method that does `obj.Property1 = dataReader["Property1"]; ...` dynamically.

```
public class Converter<T> where T : new()
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> _convertActionMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();
    private Action<IDataReader, T> _convertAction;

    private static Action<IDataReader, T> GetMapFunc()
    {
        var exps = new List<Expression>();
        var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDataReader), "dataReader");
        var targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "target");
        var getPropInfo = typeof(IDataRecord).GetProperty("Item", new[] { typeof(string) });
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var getPropExp = Expression.MakeIndex(paramExp, getPropInfo, new[] { Expression.Constant(property.Name, typeof(string)) });
            var castExp = Expression.TypeAs(getPropExp, property.PropertyType);
            //var bindExp = Expression.Bind(property, castExp);
            var bindExp = Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(targetExp, property), castExp);
            exps.Add(bindExp);
        }
        return Expression.Lambda<Action<IDataReader, T>>(Expression.Block(exps), new[] { paramExp, targetExp }).Compile();
    }

    public Converter()
    {
        _convertAction = (Action<IDataReader, T>)_convertActionMap.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), (t) => GetMapFunc());
    }

    public T CreateItemFromRow(IDataReader dataReader)
    {
        T result = new T();
        _convertAction(dataReader, result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Test method with 80,000 x 100 iteration

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dummyReader = new DummyDataReader();
    var properties = typeof(DummyObject).GetProperties();
    var startDate = DateTime.Now;
    var converter = new Converter<DummyObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 80000 * 100; i++)
    {
        //var obj = CreateItemFromRow2<DummyObject>(new DummyDataReader());
        var obj = CreateItemFromRow<DummyObject>(dummyReader, properties);
        //var obj = converter.CreateItemFromRow(dummyReader);
        dummyReader.DummyTail = i;
    }

    //var obj = CreateItemFromRow2<DummyObject>(new DummyDataReader());
    Console.WriteLine("Time used : " + (DateTime.Now - startDate).ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Result:

```
CreateItemFromRow : 18.5 seconds
Converter<T> : 7.3 seconds
```

Map function:

```
    private static IList<T> Map<T>(DbDataReader dr) where T : new()
    {
            // initialize our returnable list
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            // fire up the lamda mapping
            var converter = new Converter<T>();

            while (dr.Read()) {
                // read in each row, and properly map it to our T object
                var obj = converter.CreateItemFromRow(dr);
                list.Add(obj);
            }

            // reutrn it
            return list;
     }
```

Comment: I think I know that `Int32` error, but not sure of the rest. Could you post your class structure? and did you use my `Convert<T>` in your Map<T> method?

Comment: So, I've converted most of your code, and simply added it to my `Wrapper` class. (with some mods), it definately seems to be alot faster now.  I am testing while using the same Sproc in my DB, but with differing parameters that return the same number of records.  Do you see any way to make what I posted above more efficient?  Or do you think that's about it?

Comment: You should still use `Convert<T>` class or adapt it. The point of `Convert<T>` class is to prepare stuff for type `T`, which is cache lookup. Thread-safe cache lookup is relatively costly, and that's why I separated it to `Convert<T>` so the cache lookup was done once for the whole list.

Comment: I tried using it like that but came up with errors, that I had posted here as comments, but were never answered for, so I tried it this way.  I will attempt your class again

Comment: Once again, I get the error...  "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."

Comment: If you can share your code so please do so. It's quite hard to imagine what's happening without seeing actual code.

Comment: i created a new class, pasted your class code into it.  Updated question with the new WrapperTest

Comment: You didn't wrap the `CreateItemFromRow` call with `while` loop. You should wrap it with `while (dr.Read()) {`.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: DURRR.  What a tool.  Thank you for all this, and putting up with me.  This is faster.  .015secs faster over 10,000 records. Second iteration is over .15secs faster :)  Thank you!